# Erroneous log on hub (Marking the node http://192.168.137.1:5566 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries) and connection timeout on grid console

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

OS: Windows 10
Selenium Version: 3.13.0

Browser: Chrome

Browser Version: Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Expected Behavior** -Node should be registered successfully

**Actual Behavior** - Erroneous log on hub (Marking the node http://192.168.137.1:5566 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries) and connection timeout on grid console

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Start hub by using :

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role hub
   ```
2. Start node by using :

   ```
   java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.3:4444/grid/register -port 5566
   ```
3. Launch grid console by using:

   ```
   http://192.168.1.4:4444/grid/console
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change the command for initiating the *Selenium Grid Node* as:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.3:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

Moreover if you are registering the *Selenium Grid Node* to *Selenium Grid Hub* at `http://192.168.1.3:4444/grid/register`. The grid console *url* should be:

```
http://192.168.1.3:4444/grid/console
```